# CakePHP question: How can i get value from radiobutton and how can i call an action?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

```
<div id="rightsidesix" >

    <?php echo '<div class="class_color_title" ><b>'."Polls".'</b></div>'; ?>

    <?php

        echo '<div id="id_color_polls" >';

            echo '<p><b>Which linux distribution do you like most ?</b></p>'.'<br/>';

            $options=array('F'=>'Fedora','U'=>'Ubuntu','D'=>'Debian','O'=>'openSuse','M'=>'Mandriva','T'=>'Other');

            $attributes=array('legend'=>false);

            echo $this->Form->radio('distributions',$options,$attributes);

            echo $this->Form->button('Check',array('id'=>'id_btnpolls'));

        echo '</div>';

        echo '<br/>';

    ?>

</div>
```

Should i add these form input/radio buttons in a form ?

After clicking the button it will call jQuery function.

```
$("#id_btnpolls").click(function(){



    var valCheckedRadio = $('input[name=data[distributions]]:checked').val()

    alert(valCheckedRadio);



    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: "<?php Router::url(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'polls')); ?>,",

        data: "valCheckedRadio="+valCheckedRadio,

        success: function(prm){

            //alert(prm);

            $("#id_color_polls").html(prm);

        }

    });
})
```

Is this correct way to call an action of a controller ?

```
        url: "<?php Router::url(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'polls')); ?>,",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#id_btnpolls").click(function(){



var valCheckedRadio = $('input[name=data[distributions]]:checked', '#myForm').val()

alert(valCheckedRadio);



$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "<?php $html->url(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'polls')); ?>,",

    data: "valCheckedRadio="+valCheckedRadio,

    success: function(prm){

        //alert(prm);

        $("#id_color_polls").html(prm);

    }

  });
})
```

Comment: ok, question is how can i get value from radiobutton in polls.ctp or in polls action ?

Comment: How would i set/call posts/polls action with the button click like this array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'polls')? I haven't used form. I used only the radiobutton and the button.

Comment: u can get value from radiobutton by using $_POST['valCheckedRadio'] in polls action of polls controller.

Comment: Is there any other cakephp way to get value from descrete radio button ?  like in this way: $this->data['archive']['select_year']; and if i would use form with radio button then what would be the way to get value from radiobutton ?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you've done looks absolutely fine for me.
You can use something like this to get a value from radio group.

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

As per your url part its perfectly fine with cakephp.

Comment: ok, question is how can i get value from radiobutton in polls.ctp or in polls action ?

Comment: How would i set/call posts/polls action with the button click like this array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'polls')? I haven't used form. I used only the radiobutton and the button.